# Not able to use moq in unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq

i just started with unit testing with moq object, i am not sure if i am doing this right or not, please help !!

```
Public Class Mrr: IMrr
{ 

   public int Delete(double obj)
   {
        int rtcode = somefunction(obj);// retreiving some code from function
        int DeleteMrr= DeleteFunction(rtcode);  // delete function executes here          
        return 0;
   }

}
```

here is the interface

```
public interface IMrr
{
    int Delete(double obj);
}
```

and my test method is something like this.

```
[TestMethod()] 
public void RetrieveSaveDeleteMRR()
{      
    var FakeObject = new Moq.Mock<IMrr>();
    FakeObject.Setup(x => x.Delete(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(0);
    var Res = FakeObject.Object.Delete(10);
}
```

this is not going to the actual function to execute that method, it suppose to go there to the method or not. i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to test `Mrr.Delete()` method, you should not mock `Mrr`. You should create real instance of `Mrr` class and call its methods.

You usually want to mock `Mrr` dependencies (there are none in your example) so that real dependencies methods aren't called.

Note: You forgot to inherit `Mrr` from your interface `IMrr`.

Comment: HI,

i edited my code , can you please tell me what are the real dependencies you are talking about here?

Comment: Please check this basic tutorial for Moq - http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/basic-introduction-to-writing-unit-tests-with-moq/16

Comment: is interface necessary for the implementation?

Comment: It's not actually required. However it's a good practice to inherit your implementation from the interface and let the consumers to work through the interface, not through direct implementation class. Check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702246/Program-to-Interface-not-Implementation-Beginners

Answer (score 1):

In your example the class `Mrr` doesn't have any dependencies. To explain what is a dependency have look at the following example.

```
public class Mrr: IMrr
{ 
    // This is dependency
    IDelete _deleteObject;

    public Mrr(IDelete deleteObject)
    {
        _deleteObject = deleteObject;
    }

   public int Delete(double obj)
   {
        int rtcode = somefunction(obj);
        int DeleteMrr = _deleteObject.DeleteFunction(rtcode);  
        return 0;
   }
}

public interface IDelete
{
    int DeleteFunction(int rtcode);
}
```

This dependency is passed in in constructor so you can provide your own mock instance in tests.

Compare with this situation:

```
public class Mrr: IMrr
{ 
    // This is dependency
    IDelete _deleteObject;

    public Mrr()
    {
        _deleteObject = new DeleteClass();
    }
}
```

Everytime `new` is used it makes impossible to inject your own implementation in unit tests.

The test could then look like this.

```
[TestMethod] 
public void RetrieveSaveDeleteMRR()
{    
    // Arange
    int expected = 1;
    Moq.Mock<IDelete> deleteObjectMock = new Moq.Mock<IDelete>();
    deleteObjectMock.Setup(x => x.DeleteFunction(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(1000);
    Mrr testedObject = new Mrr(deleteObjectMock.Object);

    // Act
    int actual = testedObject.Delete(10);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```